# Making a GUI with turbo c++?

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

Note: I am new to programming and extremely new to c++.I have seen scouring google for a long time and only things i can come up with are external headers and very complicated code..
I want to do this at school, and there we are provided with Turbo C++. We can't bring any external headers in there, gotta work with whatever i've got.

I want to create a GUI. I want to create something really good for our annual project and i want to create a GUI.

I would like to make as detailed a GUI as possible, but would be satisfied if i can create as much as several text options and clicking on em triggers respective functions (I am sorry if thats not how GUIs work, i never worked with one).

Again help is highly appreciated, i understand most discussions on Stack Overflow are much more complicated than this, i appreciate you taking the time to read and (hopefully) answer a layman question.

Comment: Can't you find a school that uses a compiler produced in the last 10 years? I mean we do have C++11 now, and I'm not sure TurboC++ even covers the C++98 standard...

Comment: How much time and people do you have for your annual project? A GUI can be a serious amount of work, and if you're new to C++, that adds a lot to learn first.

Comment: Perhaps the school assignment is from the history department :-)    I have a historic Turbo C Bible book on the shelf, for sentimental reasons.

Comment: I have until april 2014, its every man for himself though. I realize a GUI is serious work, thats one of the reasons i dwell to it, will be a great thing to drive my learning. I am hoping to have someone guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Also aint easy to change schools, believe it or not but i study in one of the only 5 schools that even have Computer Science as a subject in my city(Indian city..). Churning out a great project can also help get a scholarship, which i could really use.

Comment: I remember that there was some UI library that I used to use in either Borland Pascal or Turbo C++. It was a text-based UI library, similar to "Curses", that might be useful to you. IIRC, it was part of the standard distribution of those old Borland compiler packages. I can't remember the name though. But this was all more than 15 years ago, which means I may be completely wrong and confused.

Comment: Changing school is indeed a bit far fetched. Can't you bring your own developing environment though? Free C++ dev envs are common place (especially on Linux).
Regarding how to create a GUI, look at how others GUI are done: wxWidget, Qt, Winforms... See how they're designed and how it feels to use them.

Comment: Sadly they dont allow that(They dont even allow pendrives, external HDD e.t.c in the school premises). Correct me if im wrong but all those seem like stuff that doesnt come with the default Turbo C++ build which is what i need D:.

Comment: @aayush: I just remembered that it was called "Turbo Vision" ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Vision .) It may be of some use to you, but programming with it is not trivial.

Comment: @aayush: for the toolkits I mentioned, there is indeed no way they will work with Turbo C++. But if you have a computer, you can study them at home, so you see how they're designed. Just trying to use them (and trying to understand why they require you to do certain things) will teach you a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll suggest a non-technical solution because this is actually largely not a technical problem. Much of your problem is that you have to use Turbo C++. Unfortunately, a number of poorer countries have, for some reason, stuck with extremely outdates software in education. I know because I'm originally from one of the "Turbo countries", and I know that the main technical university there still uses Turbo for undergrad courses.

*This is bad*. Large projects in school are there to teach you to work on software. A regular programming course should teach you to think like a programmer, and it doesn't matter what language you use. But term projects are supposed to be more practical. The problem is, with Turbo C++, not only will you fail to learn enough, you will learn things that are bad. You'd be writing a 16-bit program that takes effort to even run on modern hardware, while not being able to use the C++ language properly. The compiler is older than the first ISO C++ standard!

If you want to make an impressive project that will stand out in your studies, especially if you later want to continue at a foreign university, I urge you to talk to your professor, explain the situation, and ask if you can use something else for the project. A modern compiler with some framework like Qt. If you can reach an agreement to use something else, it will benefit you.

Otherwise, if you have no choice, get Turbo Vision. There are versions of BC++ packaged with it, or you can find it elsewhere, Turbo Vision is a fairly comprehensive interface framework for the dinosaur era.

Comment: Well, thanks to everybody for their comments and answers. Will look into turbovision. ALso to clear it up, im actually in High School, not college :/

Comment: I don't know while they're sticking with the ancient software while there are lots of free compilers nowadays

Answer (score 1):

First off, the toolchain and operating system you are using is outdated and incapable. And the language support Turbo C++ offers can hardly be called C++ *at all*; the code you will write will *not* be C++ code. At best, it will be *C with classes* code.

All that aside, there was a fairly-capable Text-based User Interface (TUI) library available with Turbo C++ (as well as Borland's Pascal-based toolchains,) called **[Turbo Vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_Vision)**. You might be able to use that. It generates UIs quite similar to the Turbo C++ IDE itself.

But IIRC, it was not trivial to use, so I advise you to find a book or reference or comprehensive tutorial of some kind. However, since your environment precludes anything that is not available already with TC, I see no option for you other than using **Turbo Vision** or writing your own, which doesn't sound like something you can do or want to do.

Comment: Again, this all belongs to a brief period and more than 15-16 years ago. I might be confused and wrong about all of this.